# Meta Query Returns Nothing when Too Much Data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, meta-query

I am doing a "find dealer" lookup for a company so that users can put in a zip code and a radius and find all the dealers within that radius.

It seems to work fine until I get a couple thousand zip codes.

I am passing in the array of zip codes to a `meta_query` and checking that against my custom post type `dealer` with its `key` of `zip` to find all dealers that have a zip code that is contained in the `$zip_array`.

```
  <?php
  // This takes in a zip code and returns all zip codes in a specific radius
  // using the zip code api: https://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#radius
  $api_root   = 'https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest';
    $api_key    = $ZIP_CODE_API_KEY;
    $zip_radius = isset($_POST['radius']) ? $_POST['radius'] : 25;
    $zip_code   = $_POST['zip'];
    $type       = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : array('architectural','auto','safety-security');

    $api_url    = $api_root.'/'.$api_key.'/radius.json/'.$zip_code.'/'.$zip_radius.'/miles?minimal';

    $curl = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

// Because all zip codes come back as strings, we set up an array to push 
// the new zip code integers into
$zip_array = array();

// Decode response for easy looping
$curl_response = json_decode($curl_response);

// var_dump($curl_response);

// Change zip code strings to integers and push into zip_array
foreach ($curl_response as $zipcode) {
    foreach ($zipcode as $the_zip) {
        array_push($zip_array, intval($the_zip));
    }
}

 $meta_query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'dealer',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'zip',
            'value'   => $zip_array,
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $type
        )
    )
);
$meta_query = new WP_Query( $meta_query_args );

  ?>
```

After that, I am just doing the standard `loop` and `HTML` and echoing out all the dealer information on the page. The API is returning all the zip codes as it should and everything displays as it should and displays quickly, but I have noticed that when I set the radius to `100 miles`, for some zip codes in the north east United States, it returns upwards of 2500 zip codes.

For example, 19804 at 75 miles returns around 1200 zip codes and properly displays 9 dealers. 19804 at 100 miles returns around 2200 zip codes and the display loop hits the `else` and says no dealers match that data.

100 miles at other zip codes that return only 1000 or so returns the data and displays properly.

Is this simply a case of having to check against too many zip codes or am I way off and it is something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I checked the WordPress `debug.log` and saw `Query Killed`. Googled that issue and found that on `WP Engine` hosting, they limit queries of a certain size.

So, in the `wp-config` i added the line `define( 'WPE_GOVERNOR', false );` and that took WP Engine's query limit off.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is meant by "queries of a certain size" - as in the query string is too long? Or the query results are too large? There's probably a reason (performance) that WP Engine does this, and there's also probably consequences to overriding this, so you may want to consider another approach.  `WP_Query` is "heavy" compared to a simple `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->post_meta} WHERE....")`, so you may want to consider refactoring to "lighter-weight" queries to keep your site performance up.